# Acessing a parent's get property gives "Object variable or with block..." error

Tags: excel, vba, object

A have a series of objects, a complex data structure, a parent, and a child. The child contains an instance of the parent, has Let and Get Properties, and one method. When the method requests one of the ComplexData objects from the parent, I'm given the old `RunTime Error 91 - Object Variable or With Variable not set` message. The child is packaging up all the ComplexData objects from iteself and its parent. The error is generated when the Parent `Property Get TitleField()` is called by the child.

These are the classes (in bold):

**ComplexData**

```
Private sName As String
Private vValue As Variant

Public Property Let Name(sInput As String)
    sName = sInput
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = sName
End Property

Public Property Let Value(vInput)
vValue = vInput
End Property

Public Property Get Value()
    Value = vValue
End Property
```

**ParentClass**

```
Private oTitle As ComplexData

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set oTitle = New ComplexData
    oTitle.Name = "title"
End Sub
Public Property Let Title(vInput)
    oTitle.Value = "Lorum"
End Property

Public Property Get Title()
    Value = oTitle.Value
End Property

Public Property Set TitleField(oInput As ComplexData)
    Set oTitle = oInput
End Property

Public Property Get TitleField() As ComplexData
    TitleField = oTitle         'GENERATES ERROR
End Property
```

**ChildClass**

```
Private oParent As ParentClass

Private oContentData As ComplexData

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set oParent = New ParentClass
    Set oContentData = New ComplexData
    oContentData.Name = "content"
End Sub

Public Property Let Content(sInput As String)
    oContentData.Value = sInput
End Property

Public Property Get Content() As String
    Content = oContentData.Value
End Property

Public Function getFields()
    getFields = Array(oContentData, oParent.TitleField)
End Function
```

I can get around this by setting `oTitle` to `Public` in the parent class, and requesting the object directly instead of using the `Property`.

I'm calling this from a spreadsheet using the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set MyChild = New ChildClass
    Fields = MyChild.getFields
    field0 = Fields(0).Name
    field1 = Fields(1).Name
    MsgBox field0 & field1
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `Set` statement on the line which errors out.

Comment: I get an error on `Set MyChild = New ChildClass`, because `MyChild` is not declared :D

Comment: And yes, the adding a Set here - `Set TitleField = oTitle` gets you the message box :D

Comment: I guess I didn't know I needed a Set within a Get property when returning an Object. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk you're assigning an object reference, `Set` keyword is required. Whether you're inside a `Property Get`, `Function`, or `Sub` scope makes no difference.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk I'm not sure if you have it in your module and forgot to include it but `Option Explicit` will tell you when you're using a variable that isn't declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vityata mentioned, adding a “Set” within the Get property fixes the issue.